# Symfony could not load TextType class

Tags: php, symfony

I have version 4.1 of symfony, and I tried first to install symfony/form component, and here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/jqqvdl

Next, i get this error - http://prntscr.com/jqqxdg

**Error:**

> Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\TextType":
>   class does not exist.

Anyone knows how to fix this symfony bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the correct namespace is:
`Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType`

[TextType](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TextType.html) is under `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type`, see:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
//...
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('task', TextType::class)    
    ->getForm();
```